# How to change PayPal Logo

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal, paypal-standard

I found a solution in this forum to change the paypal logo and text in the checkout of http://www.cellar2door.com to show the logo with all the credit cards on it.
The solution I found was………… 
The only place in the admin I see that seems related is: `System -> Configuration -> Payment Methods -> Paypal -> Basic Settings -> Frontend Experience Settings -> PayPal Product Logo`

An easier option may be to edit: `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\paypal\payment\mark.phtml`

from:

`<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getPaymentAcceptanceMarkSrc())?>`

to:

`<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(‘images/custom-paypal.png’); ?>`

Then in your `skin/frontend/package_name/theme_name/images/` create a custom-paypal.png
I did this and edited the text but am not sure where this folder is `skin/frontend/package_name/theme_name/images`

I have ended up with this code

```
<!-- PayPal Logo -->
<img src=”<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(‘images/custom-paypal.png’); ?> alt=”<?php echo Mage::helper(‘paypal’)->__(‘Acceptance Mark’) ?>” class=”v-middle” />&nbsp;
<a href=”<?php echo $this->getPaymentAcceptanceMarkHref()?>” onclick=”javascript:window.open(‘<?php echo $this->getPaymentAcceptanceMarkHref()?>’,’olcwhatispaypal’,’toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, ,left=0, top=0, width=400, height=350′); return false;”>
<?php if($this->getPaymentWhatIs()) {echo Mage::helper(‘paypal’)->__($this->getPaymentWhatIs());} else {echo Mage::helper(‘paypal’)->__(‘Pay By Credit Card’);} ?>
</a>
<!-- PayPal Logo -->
```

When I click on the logo that is there now which is a blue ? the path is http://www.cellar2door.com/skin/frontend/base/default/images/custom-paypal.png%20alt= So am not sure why the logo is not showing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Jim

Comment: check this link http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-removechange-the-paypal-logo.html

Answer (score 1):

You aren't closing the quotation marks for the  tag in your HTML, should be:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(‘images/custom-paypal.png’); ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper(‘paypal’)->__(‘Acceptance Mark’) ?>" class="v-middle" />&nbsp;
```

Not closing the  src attribute breaks the image.

Comment: Thanks I tried pasting that in but then it gave me an error and would not load that page,